# I'm trying to display multiple bootstrap div with each div having a carousel of images coming from database and other info

Tags: php, html, carousel, bootstrap-5

Displaying the images is working just fine.. However the other divs are displaying within the first div.. and the other information like (title, description, etc) are not showing. What I want is to display like six rows (each with two columns).. with each div having a carousel of images and other information.. I'm building a real estate website.. Please kindly help.

```
<div class="container py-4">
    <div class="row py-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1 id="stylish-font">Featured properties</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    
        <?php
            include"validations/connection.php";
            
            **Query to select data from database**

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM property order by propertyId desc";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo'
                    <div class="row py-4">
                ';
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo"
                        <div class='col-sm-6'>
                            
                        ";  
                            $id= $row['propertyId'];
                            $sqltwo = "SELECT * FROM propertyimages WHERE propertyId = '$id'";
                            $resulttwo = $conn->query($sqltwo);
                            if ($resulttwo->num_rows > 0) {
                                echo'
                                    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                                ';
                                    while ($rowtwo = $resulttwo->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        $active = $rowtwo['active'];
                                        if ($active == 1) {
                                            echo'
                                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                                    <img src="uploads/'.$rowtwo['imageName'].'" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image">
                                                </div>
                                            ';
                                        }
                                        else {        
                                            echo'
                                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                                    <img src="uploads/'.$rowtwo['imageName'].'" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image">
                                                </div>
                                            ';
                                        }
                                    }
                                echo'
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="visually-hidden>Next</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                ';
                            }
                        ";
                        
                        </div>
                    ";
                    echo"
                        <div class='row'>
                            <p>".$row['propertytitle']."</p>
                            <p>".$row['description']."</p>
                        </div>
                    ";

                }
                
                echo'
                </div>              
                ';
            }

            
        ?>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need more information... why does the variable **$no**? I do not see it useful in the code, you can put the html of the table with the loop included

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).